# Performance hit using large text files with a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a viewflipper that has about 20 long strings as child TextViews. Its very slow to load up when I start the activity and I'm guessing its because its instantiating all the child views at once. If this is the case, is there a way to get it to recycle the views in the way a list view does?

Thanks

Comment: You could implement the recycling mechanism yourself by adding and removing the `TextViews` or/and the text in them at runtime in the `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: Thank you Luksprog, you've got me thinking in a different direction :-)